# laravel 4.2 is displaying identifier than value passed from controller?

Tags: laravel

### My Route:

Route::post('dgrs', 'DgrsController@ddgr');

### Controller:

```
public function ddgr()

    {
        $dt=Input::get('dgrdate');
        $dgrs = Dgr::where('dgr_date', '=', $dt)->get();
        return View::make('dgrs.show')->with('dgrs', $dgrs);
    }
```

### View to display as table:

```
@foreach($dgrs as $dg)
 <tr>
  <td>$dg->dgr_date</td>    
  <td>$dg->mc_loc</td>
  <td>$dg->daily_gen</td>
  <td>$dg->gen_hrs</td>            
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

### Output

```
Dgr Date            loc             gen                    hrs
$dg->dgr_date       $dg->mc_loc     $dg->daily_gen         $dg->gen_hrs
```

Displaying identifier than returned value. var_dup is showing the value.

Comment: Use the `{{ $dg->dgr_date }}` syntax to "echo" variables rather than displaying them as plain text.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Make that an answer so the OP can accept it ;)

Comment: Thanks a tone Mr. Andre Daniel. It worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `{{ $variable }}` syntax to "echo" variables rather than displaying them as plain text.